# Deleting records from RemoveRegistry table

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer

I've got some registry resources that need deleting on install, but not if there are other components on the target that need them. [Ideally I'd do this by associating the resources with shared components, but I don't have that option here].

I have some shared code to run SQL commands (including DELETE statements), which works fine everywhere else, but in the present case the DELETE statement appears to go through fine, but the records just don't get dropped. I've written a query to actually check the state of the table after the DELETE command runs and it looks like only the first element of the database record is actually getting deleted, with the rest of the fields in the record left intact.
When I print out the table records, I get things like this, where the first field is empty

> ,2,SOFTWARE\xxxxxxxInstall,Version,yyyyyyy,,,
>
> MSI (s) (A8!5C) [16:49:19:628]: Database string pool is corrupted.

I changed tack and rather than just executing a DELETE command, I did an MsiViewModify on each record with MSIMODIFY_DELETE, but I get the same issue.

In the end I've had to go with just editing the records so that they refer to a different value that I know won't exist, but I don't like that, for obvious reasons.

Anyone got any suggestions about this? There was a very old bug in MSI 1.0 related to string pools, but that related to MSI database files needing to be committed, which doesn't apply in the context of a custom action where you get the handle by calling GetActiveDatabase().

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I recall reading somewhere that MSI SQL support for temp tables and rows is additive not subtractive.  You'll notice in the SDK doco that only the INSERT INTO command has the TEMPORARY option, DELETE FROM does not.

You really need to look into organizing your components better so that your registry resources can be associated to all of the various features that have components with resources that have dependencies on the registry keys.

[SQL Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372021%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: This is true, you cannot remove rows from the MSI during install. A simpler solution would be to remove the entries with a custom action. This custom action can be conditioned with a search which determines if the other components exist.

Comment: I would dispute that DELETE FROM doesn't work, since I have several other cases where the approach has worked well. Moreover, if it doesn't work, why do I not get an error when attempting to execute the SQL statement? As I made clear in the OP, the problem is not a matter of organization. If it were, then it would be a trivial matter to let MSI take care of component ref counts when deciding whether to delete these reg values or not. The shared resource is owned by a non-MSI install, so this is not really an option.